# Matrix proof check: prove that $AB=I_n$ iff $B=A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

My linear algebra is rusty and was hoping for someone to check if this proof works!

Both $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices, and $I_n$ represents the $n\times n$ identity matrix. $L_X$ will denote the linear transformation corresponding to the matrix $X$

$AB=I_n$ Directly implies that $L_B=(L_A)^{-1}$

This implies that $L_A$ is a bijection

This implies that $(L_A)^{-1}$ exists, and hence so does $A^{-1}$

Now assume that $C=A^{-1}$

We have: AB=$I_n$=AC

By the existence of $A^{-1}$ we have $B=C$

Comment: How is $B^{-1}$ defined?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. Your proof must somewhere explicitly use the fact that the matrices are square. The "Directly implies ..." needs more work.

Since $AB = I$ you know the kernel of $L_B$ must be just $\{0\}$ and $L_B$ is injective. Since $B$ is square that implies $L_B$ is surjective too, so has an inverse, which is clearly $A$.

**Edit** in response to a comment:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How come the "directly implies" part needs more work? What makes it an incorrect implication?

Comment: @martinkleins See my edit.